# Is there a way to block the Immersive Mode prompt "Swipe down from the top to exit full screen"?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, immersive-mode

When an app uses Immersive Mode, Android will often issue a large prompt (on a blue background) instructing the user to "Swipe down from the top to exit full screen".

Is there a way to prevent Android KitKat from displaying this message?

I performed some research, and the only answer I could find involved installing an Xposed Framework module.  I would prefer not to install the Xposed Framework.

Answers requiring a rooted device are fine (please just specify in your answer whether or not your solution requires root).

Comment: Note that this is a security feature. Without the notification, an app can take over the screen and emulate parts of the system that you think are part of the system.

Comment: @LieRyan Thanks.  That's good info.  Note that it doesn't always appear, so, well, that's not great security!

Comment: The reminder bubble should only appears the first time the app goes to immersive mode or if the user goes into [panic mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075041/immersive-mode-instructions-reappear-every-time-the-device-enters-this-mode). I guess this is a fine balance between security and usability. Displaying the reminder bubble every time an app enters immersive mode would be annoying.

Comment: @LieRyan Yes, there seems to be a fine balance there.  I have an app that uses immersive mode as a lock screen, so turning off the screen after it starts is a normal activity (thus triggering panic mode).  So I would like to just get rid of the message altogether.